# Receiving wrong cookie from server

Tags: android, post, android-volley

When I make a request from my android app to my server, it(server) sends a cookie but the one I'm receiving on my android app is some other cookie( Cloudflare cookie). When I make the same request through browser it shows multiple cookies (including one I'm receiving and one I need). How come my app receive only one cookie. I'm using Volley to make these calls.

How do I get the other cookies in my android app?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used Volley (1 year ago) it didn't support multiple HTTP headers with the same name.
Therefore, your header "Set-Cookie" could be replaced by CF's header "Set-Cookie".

To fix that, I forked Volley to add support for multiple headers with the same name. See my [commit](https://github.com/paristote/volley/commit/383722c24f45f0ce72d1f728bdddce07e814b3c3). To try this, checkout my repo on the branch [refactor-headers](https://github.com/paristote/volley/tree/refactor-headers), build it and use the modified jar in your app. Keep in mind that it uses an old version of Volley.

Basically, Volley used (or still use) a Map to keep the headers, like this

`map.put(headers[i].getName(), headers[i].getValue());`.

All I did was replace the Map by a List.

Comment: It looks like Volley still uses the same technique to keep the headers, i.e. a Map https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#259